# How to process encoded command line user input text?

Tags: c++, unicode

If a c++ command line application accepts characters from the user via command line then what will be the encoding of the user input?
Is there any easy way to determine the input text encoding?

what c++ functions or c++ libraries are available in Windows and Unix to deal it in common way while processing and then sending back for display on command line ?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the query the LC_* environment variables as LC_ALL. Here is a [detailed explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do).

On Windows, you should use the GetLocaleInfoEx API call [as explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getlocaleinfoex) and GetConsoleOutputCP [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleoutputcp).